# Laravel Relationships with multiple eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

Looks like I need some help with the Relationships part.For example, more than one address record of a user is kept in the database.

I can't view the address part, I think I have a problem with eloquent, but I'm not sure.

Following my code:

`user` Table

```
id |    name       | lastname |
--- --------------  ----------   

1  | Rahuel        | lastnameRahuel
2  | Dalton Miller | lastnameDalton
```

`adress` Table

```
user_id | adress         
-------- ---------
1       | 740 Brown Greens Suite  
1       | 9906 Cleora Wall Apt.      
2       | 53977 Kip Center Apt
```

`UserModel`

```
 public function getAdress()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Adress::class);
    }
```

`AdressModel`

```
 public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

`UserController`

```
$users = User::with('getAdress')->get();

        foreach ($users as $user){
            echo $user->name;
            echo $user->lastname;
            echo $user->adress;
        }
```

`user_migration`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('lastname');
        });
    }
```

`adres_migration`

```
Schema::create('adress', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
     $table->string('adress');
     $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

Comment: switch `hasMany` to user model and `belongsTo` to AdressModel. because User Has Many addresses and Address Belongs to user.

Comment: I fixed it sorry but I still can't display the address part in the foreach

Comment: `foreach ($users->getAdress` you ca loop through address as.

Comment: Please add your migrations as well. It might be an issue with the `user_id` column type which has to match the `id` column in the `Users` table

Comment: Also, for keeping things clear, when you have *ToMany relation, define your relation as plural: `public function getAdress()` should be `public function getAdresses()`

Comment: Also, the relations should not contain any verb. In this case: `getAddress()` and `getUser()` should be `addresses()` and `user()`

Comment: @JFeel please also add your migrations for the 2 tables

Comment: I've updated, you can check

Comment: just do `echo $user->getAdress->pluck('address')->join(', ');` it should work. I just create a quick sample app and it works with your exact code. Unless you have other stuff happening which might influence it. See @DevsiOdedra answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 User having multiple addresse, so `hasMany` used and it will return a list of address. so you cant access as `$user->adress;`

1. you can loop through `$users->getAdress`
2. you can display comma separated address using `pluck` and `join` as below.

`$users = User::with('getAdress')->get();`

```
        foreach ($users as $user){
            echo $user->name;
            echo $user->lastname;
            echo $user->getAdress ? $user->getAdress->pluck('adress')->join(',') : '';
        }
```

Comment: not working sorry.

Comment: whats issue? error or not getting data or what?

Comment: adress is return empty

Comment: use `dd($user->getAdress )` if your relation proper then it should display list of data.

Comment: i checked and it returned null again

Comment: `pluck` will not return a string. You need to implode (or join) it in order to display a comma separated string: `implode(', ', $user->getAdress->pluck('adress'))` - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: in User model try `return $this->hasMany(Adress::class,'user_id');`

Comment: @CornelRaiu join can do, `->pluck('adress')->join(',')`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra true. That's why I updated it with implode (or join) - under the hood it still does an implode

Comment: @CornelRaiu right.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I found the solution by doing data type hasMany in the user model, but I don't know how healthy this is.
It is going through hasMany in two models now.

Comment: data type? you have to use `hasMany` otherwise it will not get data.